# Azure Visual Studio Online Deploy step not working

Tags: azure, continuous-integration

I'm trying to implement Continuous integration for an ASP.NET website. I have an Azure Windows 2012 VM where the website should be hosted.

Right now the website has been deployed manually and works fine.

On my Visual Studio Online project, on the Build tab, I have 2 build steps - Visual Studio Build, and Windows Machine File Copy.

The Visual Studio Build works fine with no errors or warnings. The Windows Machine  File Copy fails.

Here are the settings:

[image]

And here is the error:

[image]

Any help would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue due to missing dlls on the hosted agent environment. Suggested workaround is to setup your own agent and add to VSO.

Issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/583

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.